# Is the $_GET superglobal *always* encoded in ISO-8859-1?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have both Apache and PHP configured to use UTF-8 for the default character set, yet it appears that the $_GET superglobal is still encoded in ISO-8859-1. Is the $_GET superglobal *always* encoded in ISO-8859-1?

Comment: have you restart apache after changing settings?

Comment: Can you show us your configuration settings?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted Apache. httpd.conf: AddDefaultCharset utf-8 • php.ini: default_charset = "utf-8"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$_GET` superglobal is presented to PHP however the client sent it. Neither Apache nor MySQL modify it (or its encoding) along the way.

In practice, the encoding of values in `$_GET` may depend on the browser. It's often UTF-8, but you may need to fall back to ISO-8859-1 if it isn't valid as UTF-8.

Comment: You've changed the _default_ character set. You can't force everyone else's browser to send you UTF-8. If you _need_ UTF-8, you should detect the encoding and be prepared to convert it.

Comment: So let's say I'm on a website that has a link to http://example.com/testing/index?test=r%E9sum%E9 and I either click that link or I manually paste that same link into the address bar. One web browser might send it encoded in ISO-8859-1 and another might send it encoded in something else?

Comment: If the URL is already percent-encoded, PHP just decodes it and passes it to you as raw data. It's when dealing with form input that things can get inconsistent -- for instance, if a user typed "résumé" into a form, it may end up encoded either as `r%E9sum%E9` or `r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9`.

Comment: That makes sense. So how do you suggest I process user input if I don't know the encoding that their browser will decide to use?

Comment: Sniff the encoding: try UTF-8 first, then fall back to ISO8859-1 if that doesn't work.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that *any* time I want to do *anything* with the $_GET superglobal, I should *always* run the entire $_GET superglobal through `mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1')`? Sorry for all the questions... just want to be sure I'm doing things correctly.

Comment: It's probably safest to do so, yes.